# Only 3 wires in 3 phase motor terminal box

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor, delta, star

I have a 3 phase motor with the nameplate below
[image]

At the terminal box you have your standard 6 pins labelled u, v, w, u1, v1, w1. However, the u1, v1, w1 is not connected on the terminal block but instead hardwired for star configuration inside the motor.

Is it possible to have the motor sent away to engineers in order for the other points to be exposed so I can configure the motor in delta or star?

Comment: It's a 1500rpm motor, so it has six windings in sum. Whatever you want to achieve, it will be a larger project.

Comment: Plate shows star connection

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the motor -- but a motor rewind shop* should be able to do this, particularly if the terminal box already has a place for those three wires to go.

How much it'll *cost* depends on the details of how the star connection is done inside the motor -- if it's buried under a bunch of windings, the motor will need to be completely rewound.  You won't find that out until the rewind shop has it open and is looking at it.

* Your use of the term "engineer" suggests that you speak British English and not American English -- I'm not sure what the name of the shop would be in British.  But if there's industry that uses motors, there will be shops that rewind them.

Comment: For a 3kW motor, the cost to do this would likely exceed the cost of a new motor with the desired ratings.

Comment: Certainly in the US.  Given the script on the motor, it may be in a part of the world where it's cheaper to modify than buy.